# Typo3: Get sys_file_metadata.title without Repo

Tags: php, sql, typo3

I've got a File Path (`sys_file.identifier`) and I want to get the file title (`sys_file_metadata.title`).

I need to load this in a controller of my PlugIn and just need it quick and dirty.

I first tried this:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)
  ->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_file');
  $statement = $queryBuilder ->select('sys_file_metadata.title')->join(
    'sys_file', 'sys_file_metadata', 'metadata', $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
      'metadata.file', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('sys_file.uid')
    )
  )->where($queryBuilder->expr()->like(
    'sys_file.identifier',
    $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(
      '%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards(
        str_replace(PATH_site . 'fileadmin','', $t_filename)
      ) . '%'
    )
  )
)->execute();
```

This didn't work because I'm using Typo3 7.6. So, I tried it like this:

```
$queryBuilder = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Repository');
$query = $queryBuilder->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);
$query->statement(
  'SELECT sys_file_metadata.title FROM sys_file_metadata ' .
  'INNER JOIN sys_file ON sys_file_metadata.file = sys_file.uid '.
  'WHERE sys_file.identifier "%' . 
  str_replace(PATH_site . 'fileadmin','', $t_filename) . '%"'
);
$result = $query->execute();
```

So, as I typically do with Typo 3, I'm just guessing because I could not find any information in the docs.

How can I simply load the `File-Title` of a `File` for which I already have the Path? I don't want to turn the whole world a hundred times for this; it's something so simple that it has to be quick! No additional classes or files should be required just for a stupid query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some built in functionality for this. 
Pls check out this class:
https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_resource_factory.html

There is a function called: **getFileObjectByStorageAndIdentifier**

```
$fileObject = ResourceFactory::getInstance()
->getFileObjectByStorageAndIdentifier($storageId, $identifier);
```

You can find the `$storageId` "quick and dirty" in the database. (Probably it is 1, but pls check it.) The `$identifier` you already figured out.

In the fileObject you have the possibility to get the original title of the file.

```
$fileTitle = $fileObject->getProperty('title');
```

Let me note, that this seems to be an issue with a wrong configured plugin or something. There are some really good ways how to solve an image selection with each and every advantage that TYPO3 supports.

(And please don't get frustrated if it does not work even for the 10th times, we are here and try to help you. TYPO3 is a mature system, with a pretty deep and good API and extension framework Extbase. 99,99% sure that there is an "official" solution for such problems.)

Comment: Thanks, you were a really big help!

Comment: @FuFu: you can even try to get the file Title like 
$fileTitle = $fileObject->getProperty('title');  see my edit.